# storing text area input with \n value in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I am trying to use textarea input.

I am taking the value using `$('textarea').val();`

When I add multi line input, for example like

```
    line1
    line2
```

I want to get the value as `line1\nline2` instead of the default.

Comment: Did you read this.? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941582/how-to-get-textareas-text-using-jquery-with-newline-character-preserved

Comment: Using the wrap attribute. <textarea wrap="hard">

Comment: Yes. it doesnt work in firefox..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$("textarea").val().replace(/\r?\n/g,"\\n")`

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wvp8r/5/)